# undefined index when trying to get value from textbox

Tags: php, html, yii

I’m trying to get a value from a text box named `name`. however, when I'm trying to get the value, it says, `name` is an undefined index:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 

$name = $_GET['name'];

?>
```

Comment: When using code inside the same page, use `isset()` along with a conditional statement.

Comment: upon execution, `$_GET['name']` is undefined, unless you accessed the url as `http://yoursite.com?name=myname`

Comment: first check whether it is exist or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_GET['name']` will be undefined until the form gets submitted so use this

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 

if (!empty($_GET))
    $name = $_GET['name'];
?>
```

Comment: still returns indefined index

Comment: it shouldn't!! i have tested it...